# wrapping the contents of List in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have created fixed size `List`. If the list has one item which is bigger than the List size it self, then the item should be wrapped to multiple lines.

`SWT.WRAP` can't be used as it supports only `Label` and `Text` controls.

Comment: It is not showing the full item untill i drag the list to rigth side

Answer (score 3):

For item customization of List you need to create your own widget.

Check e.g. http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11489/Custom-SWT-List-Box

In this way you will have full control on the rendering of the different items

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple lines in labels per item in a list, then you use a table instead. See the SWT snippet "[draw multiple lines in a table item](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet231.java)" for the relevant code.

The bad news is that all items must have the same height...